# MVC Dummy Link which do nothing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Like in html dummy link

```
<a href="#">link</a>
```

How this will be achieved in mvc?

I wrote this but it is referring to the dropdown pages under that Link. On hover on link I just want drop down will appear and clicking on Link will do nothing.

```
 @{
    var action = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString();
}
    @Html.ActionLink("Link", "", "", null, new {@class="selected" })


<li> @if (action == "Link1" || action == "Link2"
                          || action == "Link3" || action == "Link4")         
 { 
       @Html.ActionLink("Link", "", "", null, new {@class="selected" })
       }
    else {
       @Html.ActionLink("Link", "", "", null, new {@class="" })
    }

<li>@Html.ActionLink("Link1", "Link1action", "Controller")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Link2", "Link1action", "Controller")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Link3", "Link1action", "Controller")</li>      
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Link4", "Link1action", "Controller")</li>
```

This is the code for active link highlighting menu. Link menu is just a dummy in simple html using # in href fulfill the purpose.

Comment: Why is it necessary to use an HtmlHelper in your case? Why can't you just use the html dummy link you have on top?

Comment: I have edited my question. The reason is that I m using logics on that dummy link. In brief it don't have any view.

Comment: Have answered and edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

```
  @if (action == "Link1" || action == "Link2"
                              || action == "Link3" || action == "Link4")         
     { 
            @Html.Raw(String.Format("<a href=\"#\" class = 'selected' >link</a>" ))
           }
        else {
           @Html.Raw(String.Format("<a href=\"#\" class = '' >link</a>" ))
        }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I liked your solution. But just little issue in that it functioning properly but not displaying the link properly. in the source view it is written like &lt;a href=&quot;#&quot; class = &#39;&#39; &gt;Link&lt;/a&gt;  means it is not rendering as the code here it is just displaying as a text of html tags too..

Comment: I think that problem will be solved by using "@Html.Raw". I have updated the answer.

Comment: Yes this solved too. However, simply using this also solve that { 
           <a href="#" class="selected">Link</a>

           }
        else {
           <a href="#" class="">Link</a>

        }

Answer (score 2):

`Url.Action` and `Html.ActionLink` are, by definition, for defining a URL or HTML link that points to one of your routes.  If you want a link that does not point to one of your routes, you should simply not use these methods.

If you want to maintain uniformity of appearance (in your .cshtml files) between route links and non-route links you can do the following.

In the case of a route link, write your HTML links this way:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")" class="@selected">Text</a>
```

In the case of a non-route link, write your HTML links this way:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" class="@selected">Text</a>
<a href="#" class="@selected">Text</a>
```

Here `selected` is assumed to be a `string` that has either the value `"selected"` or `""`/`null`.

If you define a helper function:

```
string Css(string css, bool condition)
{
    return condition ? css : null;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
<a href="#" class="@Css("selected", action == "Link1")">Text</a>
```

Comment: If i use <a href="@Url.Action(null, null)" class="@selected">Link</a>
As the Link doesn't need to have any action or controller it is just the hover link if mouse on in dropdown list of menu will appear. Link itself have nothing.

Comment: @UmairRana That's why I included **"In the case of a non-route link, write your HTML links this way"**... Only use `Url.Action` if you're actually creating a URL to one of your actions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write all of your HTML as Razor. Just write the dummy link in plain HTML